# Java Base64 Encoded Image isn't showing in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, base64

I am trying to retrieve a blob from my db, convert it into a byte[] and then a base64 string and then show this in my JSP. However I am getting nothing on my JSP, not even an error in my console.
Here is my code for getting blob etc.

```
        Blob blob = post.getImage();
        int blobLength = (int) blob.length();  
        byte[] blobAsBytes = blob.getBytes(1, blobLength);
        String img = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(blobAsBytes));
        
        System.out.println(img);
        model.addAttribute("img", img);
```

And this is how I'm attempting to show the image in the JSP

```
     <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,${img}" width="100" height="100"></img>
```

This is my page source:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,c2hhbG9t" width="100" height="100"></img>
```

What am I doing wrong here, when I convert the same photo on the web it outputs a huge string rather than just c2hhbG9t. Is there anyway I can get this large string.
Many thanks.
Jim

Comment: `c2hhbG9t` is far to short to be a valid image yet the code to retrieve the BLOB looks ok. It looks as if the database doesn't contain a valid image in the first place. Run a SQL query to check the size of the BLOB.

Comment: BTW: `c2hhbG9t` decodes as `shalom`.